# Ping two computers behind cascaded routers, each router has its own network

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

Basic schema here:

```
Internet
    |  
    |  
x.x.x.x (WAN)
ADSL Main Router 1
255.255.255.0  
192.168.1.1 (LAN)(DHCP)
    |  
    +-----------------------------------------+
    |                                         |
    |                                         |
192.168.1.33 (WAN)                     192.168.1.234
Ethernet Router 2                    **PC 1** (Windows)
255.255.255.0                        
192.168.0.1 (LAN)(DHCP)
    |
  wi+fi
    |                             
192.168.0.103              
**PC 2** (Ubuntu)
```

The main problem is: How do I `ping` from `PC 2` to `PC 1`? (Solved)

New problem: How do I `ping` from `PC 1` to `PC 2`?

Some affirmations:

- `Router 2` brand is TP-LINK
- `Router 2` acts as A Cascaded Router and I followed this guide http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=132275#b to achieve so
- `Router 2` network is different than `Router 1`'s
- `PC 2` is connected to its network through Wi-Fi, any other is wired-connected
- I would want to leave the subnetworks and cascading as is because Not To LAN-to-LAN
- The secondary objective of this is that I want to RDP `PC 1` (Remote Desktop)
- Each local IP is provided through DHCP (`Router 1`: `192.168.1.33` to `192.168.1.64` -> this is correct ; `Router 2`: `192.168.0.100` to `192.168.0.199`)
- From `PC 2`: I can `ping` Router 1 LAN (192.168.1.1)
- From `PC 2`: I can `ping` Router 2 WAN (192.168.1.33)

Output from `PC 2` terminal:

```
iqbal@omen:~$ ping 192.168.1.234
PING 192.168.1.234 (192.168.1.234) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.33 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.33 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

iqbal@omen:~$ traceroute 192.168.1.234
traceroute to 192.168.1.234 (192.168.1.234), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.0.1)  4.525 ms  6.847 ms  7.719 ms
 2  192.168.1.33 (192.168.1.33)  2991.898 ms !H  2992.679 ms !H  2993.563 ms !H
```

Comment: It should just work though?

Comment: Destination Host Unreachable :(

Comment: Are you sure the firewall on PC 1 is set to allow ping? IIRC the Windows Firewall’s “Public” profile does not allow it by default. // Also, is PC 1 even turned on and connected to the network?

Comment: I'll check the firewall. Also do you know which rule should I disable? Yes it is turned on and Connected.

Comment: I completely disabled Windows firewall on PC1 and still cannot ping

Comment: I could solve the main problem but can someone explain me why `PC1` cannot `ping` `PC2`?

Comment: If you add proper static routes on all devices it will work. Your chart does not include the netmasks so it is hard to say, but pc1 needs a route to 192.168.0/24 through 192.168.1.33. if the netmask on router 1 is wrong then pc2 might have problems, otherwise router 1 needs a route to 192.168.0.0/24 through 192.168.1.33 unless your router 2 is doing NAT. In that case you never can ping pc2 from pc1

Comment: @eckes what do you want to say with `"pc1 needs a route to 192.168.0/24 through 192.168.1.33" ` . Both routers have 255.255.255.0 as subnet mask (Please see the scheme again). `Destination network address can not be within the subnet of IP address WAN` error is thrown when I try to add a static route on `Router 2` with the following parameters: `Destiny: 192.168.1.0; Sub.Mask: 255.255.255.0; Def.Gateway: 192.168.1.1`. Also, I'm not sure if `Router 2` is doing NAT...`Router 2` leases IPs from 192.168.0.x. Is that doing NAT?

Comment: Oh also in `Router 1` I cannot set the Default Gateway parameter in order to create a static route. I think it is because R1 is an ADSL Router.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar network schema and issue:

- As pointed in the comments: It should work. The mistake here was some previous 'misconfigurations' since an IT guy from my Internet provider came to check some telephone issues and other things I have messed around. But the thing is It should work.
- No firewall should interfere in this topic
- `PC 2` can connect to `PC 1` but, at least in my case, not vice versa